# How do I install Google Chrome?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, google-chrome

First I asked this at AskUbuntu:

> I've been trying to install .deb chrome file `google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb`. It is saved in my Downloads, so I tried this command
>
> `sudo apt-get install ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb`
>   After reading the package list it responds:
>
> `E: Unsupported file /home/stockton/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb` given on command line
>   I don't know why it says E: file, I though Linux drives and files are not named after letters like Windows drives, for example 'C:' but idk I can still be wrong. I did have Windows 10 before I booted Ubuntu.
>
> Any help will be great.

And then someone suggested I perform this command:

> The conventional way is to install using dpkg. It is a new feature of apt to install from deb files. That's why the correct syntax is not always clear. man apt doesn't tell much either.
>
> So a guaranteed way is to copy the deb file to your Home directory and running
>
> `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
>   If it is the first time you install Chrome, you will get some error messages regarding missing dependencies. You can fix it by
>
> `sudo apt install -f`
>   Instead of copying to Home you can use the path
>
> `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Now when I tired the `sudo apt -i` command, the computer was processing the downloaded chrome files and puts on the screen:
`Errors were encountered while processing: google-chrome-stable`
I don't know what to do now please help me.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about *" If it is the first time you install Chrome, you will get some error messages regarding missing dependencies. (...)*?!? Why did you post a duplicate of your first question, badly formatted and hard to read?